# Import same named function from to same named packages

Tags: perl

I'm trying to call a function from a package that has the same name with another package in different directory, and the functions are the same name also.

Explanation:
let's say that i have `package1.pm` that exists in `dir1/` as `dir1/package1.pm`

inside it `sub fun1` is the one that i want to call

```
package package1;

sub fun1($$$)
{
    #anything;
}
```

the second package is inside anothee dir: `dir2/package1.pm`

```
package package1;

sub fun1($$$)
{
    #anything;
}
```

suppose that the functions will take the same number of parameters.

is there any way to call the function that i want exactly?

Comment: Do you want both of them in the same process? Is this about using different versions of the same thing?

Comment: Is something wrong with using fully qualified names?

Comment: The most naive way that comes to my mind to do what you're asking is not a good way (brings up a warning), but works (and still, not recommended which is why I'm not posting this as an answer):
    `unshift @INC, "yourpath/dir1";
    do 'p1.pl';
    package1::sub1();

    shift @INC;

    unshift @INC,"yourpath/dir2";
    do 'p1.pl';
    package1::sub1();`

Comment: @yonyon100 brrrr, `do`. But that might actually work. It just will not remember that it loaded those files. And please, don't include _.pl_ files. If it has namespaces, it should be _.pm_ files.

Comment: @simbabque I know, I know, `do` is a bad practice and including `.pl` files is bad, but `do` will work because it doesn't remember which files it loaded (unlike `require`) and I wrote `.pl` in include because I ran a quick try on this and didn't pay much attention to the suffix. Of course you're right, it should be `.pm`.

Comment: @yonyon100 it's actually a good suggestion if it comes with he right disclaimer and an explanation of why and how it works. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to name the packages based on the directories (for eg `Dir1::Package1`, `Dir2::Package1`) on which they are; and keep them into same base (/lib in this case) directory:

```
/lib--
     |
      ---/Dir1--
     |        |
     |        --Dir1::Package1
     |
     |
     ---/Dir2--
              |
              -- Dir2::Package1
```

Then in the script you can fully qualify the *subroutine* name to call from those packages according to your wish:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib qw(./lib);
use Dir1::Package1;
use Dir2::Package1;

# call from Dir1 Package1
Dir1::Package1::fun();

# call from Dir2 Package1
Dir2::Package1::fun();
```

Comment: Actually having `qw(fun)` on both of the `use` statements makes no sense. It would import the first, then overwrite it with the second. If you want to call the fully qualified names anyway, tell it to not import anything, because why bother.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks, Tried to be extra verbose, sounds wrong. Anyways edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start of by saying that the way I'm suggesting is highly not recommended and will bring up a warning.
The most naive way that comes to my mind to do what you're asking is using `do`:

```
unshift @INC, "yourpath/dir1";
do 'package1.pm';
package1::sub1();

shift @INC;

unshift @INC,"yourpath/dir2";
do 'package1.pm';
package1::sub1();
```

Let's say that `sub1` prints the current directory, so the output will look like this:

```
dir1
Subroutine sub1 redefined at   yourpath/dir2/package1.pm line 8.
dir2
```

Again, don't use that unless you don't care for some reason for warnings. It's a bad practice that can cause a lot of future bugs.

**Why it works:**
`do` loads the code and doesn't remember that it loaded it, meaning that in another invocation of `do` with a package of the same name, it will be overriden. Usually you won't use `do`, but `require` that does remember it loaded a package. The code attached uses `do` twice. the second time overrides the first one which is why the output looks as it does.